# How to use Jquery to check class field on chosen select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some HTML with a form and a select option like the one below...

```
      <select id="typeofrequest" name="type">
        <option value="">PLEASE SELECT</option>
        <option value="email" class="color size font">Logo request</option>
        <option value="email">Image request</option>
...
```

I have some divs further down the page and SOME of them have the class of "size".  So basically, when someone chooses "Logo request" (which has the class of "size") from the Select dropdown, I want that to trigger the other divs with class of "size" to appear/show (since they are display: none; to start).

```
if ($("#typeofrequest option").hasClass("size")) {
        $("div.size").show();
    }
```

However, with my current code, the divs with the class of "size" display no matter which select option I choose (i.e. if I chose "Image request" it still then reveals/shows the other divs. So clearly I'm not understanding something with how select and its options are read. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try `$("#typeofrequest option:selected")` - but this is bad code - use the value of the select `if($("#typeofrequest option:selected").val() == 'size'){ ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
  $('#typeofrequest').on( 'change', function( e ) {
      if( $(this).find('option:selected').hasClass("size") )
          $('div.size').show();
      else
          $('div.size').hide();
  });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gbfmevjw/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  I tried to edit it by adding the else statement (to hide divs if size is NOT in the class), but that seemed to conk out. Is this wrong formatting?: $('#typeofrequest').on( 'change', function( e ) {
      if( $(this).find('option:selected').hasClass("size") ) {
          $(".size").show();
   } else {
    $(".size").hide(); 
   }
 });

Comment: @user3304303 I have updated my code with a demo as well. Do accept the answer if it helped so others can see it as well. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks so much. Had no idea the curly brackets weren't necessary.  And really appreciate the JSFiddle demo.  Thanks again

Comment: Brackets are not necessary when you have only one command to execute. Just like in the example. If you add multiple commands, you need brackets. `if ( true ) { alert(1); console.log(1); } else console.warn(2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this:

    $(document).on('change', '#typeofrequest', function(){
        console.log($(this).find(':selected').val().hasClass('size'));
        if($(this).find(':selected').val().hasClass('size')){
            $("div.size").show();
        }else{
            $("div.size").hide();
        }
    });
```